# Absolutely position div to body not parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several child div's that I need to absolutely position to the body element.

I can't use `position: absolute` because the divs are not children of the body.

I can't use `position: fixed` because I need the divs to scroll *with* the page.

I can't use '.detach()`or`.append(element)' because of the way the CSS cascades and targets the child divs.

I'm assuming I could work out the top and left distances from the viewport to the edge of the div – and then apply those as a negative 'top:' and 'left:' to the child divs.

I'm not sure how to go about this.

Am I even thinking about this the right way? Your help and expertise would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Those child divs are directly child of tag body? or not?

Comment: No, they're not direct children of the body.

Comment: Could you show us your code, please

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you are asking but my assumption is if you use a fixed position  and just adjust it when the user either resizes or scrolls.  Just replace the TOP_POS and LEFT_POS with where it needs to be positioned.

```
$(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
    $('YOUR_DIV').css({ 
    'top': TOP_POS - $(window).scrollTop(),
    'left': LEFT_POS - $(window).scrollLeft()
    });
})
```

If this is not what you are looking for, then please disregard.